# How to clear last bind()-ed event callback in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, closures, jquery-events

I need to dynamically bind() the `click` event, but the problem is when I bind for the second or third time, last bind()-ed callbacks will also trigger. How can I clear last bind()-ed event callbacks? And overwrite `click` event with this new callback func?

Note that `event` is a user-defined object, and not Javascript event object.

```
function showEditModal(event, callback)
{
    $("#dialog-form").dialog('open');

    $('#place').val(event.metadata.place);
    $('#type').val(event.metadata.type);
    $('#city').val(event.metadata.city);

    $('#dialog-form .button-save').show().click(function()
    {
        event.metadata.place = $('#place').val();
        event.metadata.type = $('#type').val();
        event.metadata.city = $('#city').val();

        $('#dialog-form').dialog('close');
        
        callback(event);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/)? This method is identical to .bind(), except that the handler is unbound after its first invocation. (based on jQuery docs)

Comment: Yeah, its working, its a shame that i didn't pay attention to one() when i saw it yesterday. Thank you